# Sorting output using CUSTOMPSOBJECT and sorting the output by variable

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am attempting to sort the output for my daily server report by the $servername variable, however, I am failing to get the output to sort. I am thinking it needs some kind of array or select-object string. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Also, if there is a way to separate each new $servername with an empty row, that would be amazing!

- Added full script for better understanding

  ```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $server = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "searchbase" -filter *).name

    $scriptblock = {

    # Set the server name
    $serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    # Get the up/down status of the server
    $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server.Name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 1) {
        'Up'
    }
    else {
        'Down'
    }

    # Get the server build date
    $buildDate = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate

    # Certificate name information
    $certname = get-childitem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ |
        Select friendlyname 

    # Get the server certificate validity
    [array] $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
        Where-Object { -Not $_.PSIsContainer } |
        Sort-Object -Property NotBefore        

    #Number of Certs on Machine
    $certcount = (get-childitem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\my).count

    # Check Trellix update
    $TrellixDate = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat').LastWriteTime.DateTime

    # Operating system collection
    $os = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption

    # Disk information
    [array] $diskInfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3'

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Math]::Max($cert.Count, $diskInfo.Count); $i++) {
        $disk = $diskInfo[$i]
        $freeSpace = $diskSize = $percent = $label = $null

        $cert = $certs[$i]

        if ($disk) {
            $label = $disk.DeviceID
            $freeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
            $diskSize = $disk.Size / 1GB
            $percent = '{0:P0}' -f ($freeSpace / $diskSize)
        }

        $validTo = $validFrom = $null
        if ($cert) {
            $validTo = $cert.NotAfter
            $validFrom = $cert.NotBefore
        }

      #SQL Version
       if (test-path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
       $sql = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
        foreach ($i in $sql) 
        {
        $sqlver = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i
        (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version
        }
       }
       else {$sqlver = "n/a"}

    #IIS version, if available
      if (Get-Service -Name W3SVC -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
      $IIS = (Get-ItemProperty -PATH 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\').VERSIONSTRING
               }
       else {$iis = "n/a"}

  #Describing the Columns for Output
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName           = $serverName
            Status               = $status
            OperatingSystem      = $os
            BuildDate            = '{0:u}' -f $buildDate
            CertName             = $certname
            CertCreated          = $validFrom
            CertExpiration       = $validTo
            CertCount            = $certcount
            TrellixLastUpdate    = $TrellixDate
            SQLVersion           = $sqlver
            IISVersion           = $IIS
            DiskLabel            = $label
            Freespace            = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $freespace
            DiskSize             = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $disksize
            PercentFree          = $percent

                    }
    foreach ($serverName in 'PSCustomObject') { $obj | where-object {$_.Servername -eq $servername} | Sort-Object $servername }
    #foreach ($serverName in 'PSCustomObject') { $obj | where-object {$_.Servername -eq $servername} | Sort-Object $servername }
    }
  ```

  }

  ```
    #command to run the script on the servers

   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -HideComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId, PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName |
    #Export-Csv e:\activetasks\server_checks\DailyServerReport.csv -NoTypeInformation -force
    Export-Csv c:\Nec\DailyServerReport1.csv -NoTypeInformation -force
  ```

Comment: How are you using this PsObject in your code? Is it output in a loop perhaps and have you captured the output of that loop in a variable (which will then be an array of objects)? In that case, assume your variable holding the objects is called `$results`, then simply do `$results | Sort-Object ServerName`

Comment: I fixed the post to include the full script for a better understanding. The foreach beneath the pscustomobject seems to work - sorta - it writes pscustomobject under each server name

Comment: You should add `Sort-Object ServerName |` as extra line BEFORE writing it all to file with Export-Csv. In the scriptblock remove the line `foreach ($serverName in 'PSCustomObject') { $obj | where-object {$_.Servername -eq $servername} | Sort-Object $servername }` because it doesn't make sense. Also try and fix your code indentation because now it is very difficult to read

Comment: So, I cleaned it up on my end, not sure why it posted weird. It cleared up the extra data, but didn't sort the entire output alphabetically so to speak. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite of your code which hopefully shows how to capture the resulting objects, sort them and write to Csv file

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory


# prepare the scriptblock to run on connected machines
$scriptblock = {
    # Operating system collection
    $os = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption

    # Get the server build date
    $buildDate = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate

    # Disk information
    $diskInfo = @(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3')

    # Certificate info
    $allCerts = @(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My)
    # Get the server certificate validity
    $certs = $allCerts | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object -Property NotBefore        

    # Check Trellix update
    $TrellixDate = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat').LastWriteTime.DateTime

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Math]::Max($cert.Count, $diskInfo.Count); $i++) {
        $freeSpace = $diskSize = $percent = $label = $null

        if ($diskInfo[$i]) {
            $label = $diskInfo[$i].DeviceID
            $freeSpace = $diskInfo[$i].FreeSpace / 1GB
            $diskSize = $diskInfo[$i].Size / 1GB
            $percent = '{0:P0}' -f ($freeSpace / $diskSize)
        }

        $validTo = $validFrom = $null
        if ($certs[$i]) {
            $validTo = $certs[$i].NotAfter
            $validFrom = $certs[$i].NotBefore
        }

        # SQL Version, if available
        $sqlver = if (Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances | ForEach-Object {
                $p = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).$_
                if ($p) { (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version }
            } | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        if (!$sqlver) { $sqlver = "n/a" }

        # IIS version, if available
        $iis = if (Get-Service -Name W3SVC -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                    (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\').VersionString
               }
               else { "n/a"}

        # Output info as PsCustomObject
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName        = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Status            = 'Up'
            OperatingSystem   = $os
            BuildDate         = '{0:u}' -f $buildDate
            CertName          = $certs[$i].FriendlyName
            CertCreated       = $validFrom
            CertExpiration    = $validTo
            CertCount         = $allCerts.Count
            TrellixLastUpdate = $TrellixDate
            SQLVersion        = $sqlver
            IISVersion        = $iis
            DiskLabel         = $label
            Freespace         = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $freespace
            DiskSize          = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $disksize
            PercentFree       = $percent
        }
    }
}


# enter a valid DN for the searchbase here
$searchBase = 'CN=Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=com'
$servers = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $searchBase -Filter *).Name
$result  = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # Get the up/down status of the server
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -HideComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    else {
        # Output info as PsCustomObject for the disconnected server
        # create a similar object as for the connected servers with most elements empty
        "" | Select-Object @{Name = 'ServerName'; Expression = {$server}},
                           @{Name = 'Status'; Expression = {'Down'}},
                           OperatingSystem, BuildDate, CertName, CertCreated, CertExpiration, CertCount,
                           TrellixLastUpdate, SQLVersion, IISVersion, DiskLabel, Freespace, DiskSize, PercentFree
        }
    }

# Sort the resulting objects by property ServerName and write to CSV file
$result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunSpaceId |
          Sort-Object -Property ServerName |
          Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Nec\DailyServerReport1.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a simple `$ArrayList | Sort-Object -Property ServerName | Format-Table` with `$ArrayList` being a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`(which is better than regular arrays most of the time) variable containing the various `[PSCustomObject]` should do the trick.

You might even not need the space between lines.